# WEBSOcket передача фала  между клиентами

Tags: comet, websocket

Вопрос может показаться тупым, но всетаки спрошу.
Возможно ли с помощью websocket реализовать передачу файла между пользователями на прямую, не отправляя сам файл сначала на сервер?  Т.е. я вижу это так, сначала пользователь загружает файл на сервер, потом только от туда, уже другой пользователь скачивает файл. 
Хотелось бы как нибудь не хранить файл на сервере, а сразу же на прямую передавать файл, как бы в реальном времени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя. Если вы хотите передавать файл непосрадственно между клиентами, то кто-то должен выступать в роли сервера, а кто то в роли клиента. Технология Web-Socket не позволяет создавать сервер на клиенте, так что только через сервер.

Comment: непомню где, встречал пример реализации обмена сообщениями в реальном времени, сообщения ни где не хранились, но успешно отображались у клиентов, которые были подключены к серверу. Вот хотелось бы, что-то такое сделать, но только с файлами

Comment: Ну так нет проблем в этом.

Шлем на сервер команду, аля "передай клиенту пупкину", "... данные ... "

сервер ищет в активных соеденениях клиента пупкина и шлет ему "... данные ..." не сохраняя их у себя

Comment: ладно, спасибо буду пробовать)